# How to design the button below in HTML and CSS

Tags: html, css

Can someone help to design the button below using HTML and CSS.

Kindest regards

[image]

Comment: Set background image to this

Comment: Honestly though, I am afraid SO doesn't work the way you imagine.

Comment: Please read [ask] and how to post a [mcve], in short -- in order to get code you need to post code...of course if you just wanted an image for the image you posted then you're good.

Comment: Several CSS properties might help you here - border-radius box-shadow, linear-gradient background-images, pseudo elements etc. Give it a go and if still stuck put the code you have got into your question describing what the problem with it is.

Comment: Thank you so much for the code. I try it and I think it is what I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

```
 <div>
    <button class=btn-check>checkout</button>
</div>
```

```css
        div{
padding:8px;
border:1px solid #000 ; 
box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 1px #fff; 
background-color:#cbcbcb ; 
border-radius : 12px ; 
display: inline-block;
margin-left : auto ; 
margin-right: auto;
}
.btn-check{
  font-size:22px ; 
  border-radius : 8px ; 
  padding: 12px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 600;
 
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #dcdcdc, #f7f7f7);
  cursor: pointer; 
}
.btn-check:hover{
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #f7f7f7, #dcdcdc);
}
```

```html
  <div>
        <button class=btn-check>checkout</button>
    </div>
```